# GPU-intensive Android game with small APK (for tests)

Tags: android, game, performance-analysis, benchmarking

I want to test my new Android phone in terms of performance, so I need a game that makes considerable use of the graphical processing power of the phone.
The game has to have a small APK size because of my Internet bandwidth limitations.
You might recommend benchmarking software, but I prefer do it with games.